# How fast do games in Flash C++ Compiler execute compared to C++?

Tags: c++, flash, performance

Flash Player can now run C++ code, that is cross complied with the Adobe [Flash C++ Compiler](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/). How fast does such code run in comparison to a C++ application running as an EXE, in the context of gaming?

And does GPU rendering performance compare with C++ applications? Or is Flash far behind?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done here. Did you re-ask [a question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38586/rendering-performance-in-flascc-udk-when-compared-to-stage3d-and-udk-on-window/45172#45172) that someone else asked and you answered? Providing the exact same answer for both?

Comment: Yes, I did that because my answer was more general and on his page no one would really find it. My answer wasn't about UDK in specific and there was no way I could delete his entire question to broaden the scope. And the answer isn't the "exact same", I modified it for this question.

Comment: @Byte56 http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: Thanks. I thought the questions would be similar enough for them to be closed as a duplicate, instead of providing the same answer. I see that they're different enough now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GPU rendering speed** for 3D FlasCC games/apps is likely to be similar to C++ apps for obvious reasons - the actual rendering takes place on the GPU. Flash includes a cross-platfrom shader language (AGAL) to describe GPU kernels (programs run per pixel on the GPU).

**CPU/computing speeds** however at best reaches 15% the speed of MS VC++ on Windows (tested with a simple encryption function operating on an array of bytes). Some benchmarks for the latest FlasCC are available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuGZwZWm3Xv_dFBqX2tJU3owY2psVGlwcTFnSW1kd2c&hl=en_US#gid=0), that compare a set of C++ programs running as an EXE and in Flash Player.

This essentially comes down to:

- Anything you can move to the GPU can possibly be done close to native speeds. This includes rendering, lighting, mip-mapping, and to some extent physics operations (depends on the library)
- Anything still done on the CPU will be a few *times* slower than C++, so don't expect to have a million moving objects on screen with full physics even if you can do that with the native (C++) library.
- Flash vector graphics does not use the GPU and is rendered fully on the CPU. So if you need HUDs (heads up displays) with high-performance 3D vector rendering like what [Scaleform](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform) provides for C++ apps,  don't expect that to be easily possible in Flash Player, unless you're willing to roll your own 3D vector renderer that takes advantage of the GPU to composite vector shapes.